# How to recover from this NIS & NFS client error?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs, authentication, nis

I have a centralized NIS and NFS server on my server. I use this server to control 100 Linux clients, `/$home/` directory and authentication are served by the centralized server. The other day in one of my clients unfortunately I disconnected the Ethernet connection (from the top panel), and the whole set-up was collapsed. Now I cannot login to that machine.

It shows sort of  `yp bind error`.

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try restarting NIS server since it was unreachable during the disconnection the yp has not binded yet again. So restarting should help here.

Comment: Its of no use. To connect to server, Ethernet should be up. But I can't get inside system so as to enable.

Comment: If possible reboot the box.

Comment: Same issue after reboot.

Comment: Is ethernet still not connected ?. If ethernet is connected after reboot NIS should connect again and will get up.

Comment: I'll Ethernet cable is already connected but, I disconnected it at the GUI interface of the ubuntu

Comment: If the connection doesn't come up automatically after a reboot, then it's probably a hardware failure (cable, eth card, ...)

Comment: ...or a configuration fault. Using CLI instead of GUI for things like networking configuration may provide a less bumpy road.